# How can I add a specific jar only in a specific folder with Maven?

Tags: maven-2

i have a maven project using the maven soapui plugin.

Unfortunately this one in my case need an external jar for jdbc for
some groovy scripts.

And according to their documentation, you have to add a repertory called "ext".
And after a dig in their code, this path is hardcoded in their plugin source. 
You cant specify it.

So i have to add it directly to a subdirectory of MyProject :
Myproject/ext/postgresql.X.X.jar

I dont want to commit a jar in my project.

**Is there a way to tell to maven to pickup a specific jar& add it to a specific directory ?**
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use maven-dependency-plugin configured in your pom file to copy the artifact into that location during the generate-resources phase, something like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-postgresql-artifact</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/ext</outputDirectory>
          <!-- if you need to rename the jar -->
          <destFileName>postgresql.X.X.jar</destFileName>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
              <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
              <version>X.X</version>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```